# ¿Cómo elimino duplicados de listas en un dataframe?

Tags: python, lista, eliminar-duplicados

cuento con la siguiente base de datos:

```
df['match'] = [[0,1,2],[3,4],[0,1,2]]
```

Quisiera eliminar de mi df las filas que duplican mi subset de match, que a su vez en un elemento de lista, y quedarme con:

```
df['match'] = [[0,1,2],[3,4]]
```

No puedo usar un drop_duplicates porque el elemento es una lista

Gracias

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a [es.so], te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask]. ¿Qué has intentado hacer hasta el momento? Parte importante de la cultura del sitio es que los usuarios publiquen sus preguntas junto con lo que han intentado, de esa forma se demuestra que has hecho un esfuerzo por resolver tu pregunta/problema, de lo contrario probablemente la pregunta termine cerrada y/o votada negativamente.

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias forma que podrías consultar en: [Removing duplicates from a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213923/removing-duplicates-from-a-list-of-lists), una bien básica, es crear una nueva lista, agregando cada elemento si este no existe:

```
lista = [[0,1,2],[3,4],[0,1,2]]

def remove_duplicates(lista):
  nueva_lista = []
  for i in lista:
    if i not in nueva_lista:
      nueva_lista.append(i)
  return nueva_lista

remove_duplicates(lista)

[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4]]
```